# Algorithm that finds minimum distance travelled while reordering a set of boxes with a forklift

Tags: algorithms, optimization

**Question**:  There are n+1 loading docks. a permutation of boxes 1->n is placed on the first n. there is a fork that can move one box to an empty location at a time.   Give an algorithm to sort then boxes with minimum distance travelled.

**Answers**:

*Case A*:  If distance travelled includes distance traveled by the fork without a box, then it is also an algorithm to minimize number of operations and can be done in-place. So, In-place quick-sort or heap-sort.

*Case B*:  If distance travelled only includes that done with a box, then  the following heuristic algorithm comes to my head

```
empty dock = N
for(index = N-1,...0)
   if(dock[index] == index) continue;

   if(dock[N] == index) move dock[N] to index
   else
      search for dock, X, s.t dock[X] == index
           move dock[index] to dock[empty dock] (initially dock[N])
           move dock[X] to dock[index]
           if(dock[empty dock] == X) move dock[empty dock] to dock[X]
           else empty dock = X
```

Basic idea is that this minimizes the distance travelled to move a box to its final location.  But I don't know if this leads to global minimum since there is also the temporary storage of the displaced box (Starting from N-1 tries to minimize the temporary movement of displaced box but I don't know if this always holds as the algorithm continues).

I don't have the mathematical background to prove it is minimizes distance. Is there some well known algorithm that this problem maps to or is there a mathematical way to come up with algorithm the leads to minimum?

Comment: "I don't have the mathematical background to prove it is minimizes distance." -- Umm, so go get it? Why do you think it's a good idea to dabble in optimization algorithms if you have no expertise in that area?

Comment: Any advice on where I can start? :)

Comment: Pick up any introductory book on algorithms. Personally, I'd recommend Sedgewick & Wayne.